# Neo4j Cypher query slow to find common children. What is the best approach?

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j - 2.1.6. In my graph any given node can have multiple parents and multiple children that are also parents and children of other nodes. What I need to do is find those parents and children that several searched nodes all have in common. The searched nodes can be one to hundreds of relations away from their common parent or child. All nodes have the same label.

I'm using the following cypher query but it is very slow when you add more than a couple nodes.... I'd like to search 20 or more nodes at a time for their common connections. Here i'm searching for children on 4 nodes:

```
MATCH (n1)-[*]->(x), (n2)-[*]->(x), (n3)-[*]->(x), (n4)-[*]->(x)
WHERE n1.name = "node1" AND n2.name ="node2" AND n3.name ="node3" AND n4.name ="node4"
RETURN DISTINCT x.name
```

Is there some other way I should be approaching this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the labels, and make sure you have an index on :Label(name)

e.g. if you labels is `:Node`

```
create index on :Node(name);

MATCH (n1:Node)-[*]->(x),(n2:Node)-[*]->(x),(n3:Node)-[*]->(x),(n4:Node)-[*]->(x)
USING INDEX n1:Node(name)
USING INDEX n2:Node(name)
USING INDEX n3:Node(name)
USING INDEX n4:Node(name)
WHERE n1.name = "node1" AND n2.name ="node2" AND n3.name ="node3" AND n4.name ="node4"
RETURN DISTINCT x.name
```

For very long paths Cypher can have some issues.

If that is a frequent operation in your graph that must finish in milliseconds, I recommend creating an server extension for Neo4j server written in Java.

Comment: This is great thanks! It now takes a fraction of the time. Are long paths just a weakness of Cypher or are they problematic with Neo4j in general?

Comment: Only a weakness of the rule-based planner in 2.1. This will change in 2.2 (you can also try to prefix your query with cypher 2.1.experimental and see what happens)